# Connect to school network drive

Tags: networking, drive

I have a problem: My school have a network drive, called I:\, which i can connect to from Windows 8, but i cant do it from Ubuntu :( I am a complete Linux noob, so its probably just because i dont know how to, but i write the info i need to connect from windows, so i hope you will help me :)

> Share (At least i think so):
>   \vihcafil11.global.local\elevhome$\ums\htx\*username*
>  Username:
>   Global\*username*
>  Password: *password*

If you know how to do it, please help me ^^

Jonas Strand

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You have to just open `Network` in nautilus file Manager. You will get folder named `Windows Network`. You will find your shared drive vihcafil11 there.

Or Open file manager, Press `Ctrl+L`  Type

```
smb://<hostname or ip of shared machine on network>
```

For example

```
smb://ketan or smb://192.168.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
2. Then type `smb://vihcafil11.global.local/elevhome$/ums/htx/` address bar. If you know the file server ip address, you may type the ip address too.
3. Type Your username and password on the pop-up box

Comment: Hmm... What if i want to log on as a domain? Is that the same as in windows? :)

Comment: You mean you want to join your ubuntu machine into windows domain?

Comment: Pretty much, the domain is named "Global", and the way you do it in windows is by typing "Global\*username*", and then you connect through the domain

Answer (score 0):

- Please open your folder (or nautilus)
- In the menu select "File->Connect to Server..."
- In the appearing dialog choose type "Windows share"
- Fill-in: Server, Share-name, Domain, User and
  Password
- Click "Connect"

Maybe you have to use the old style Windows domain name.

Comment: When i push the "Connect to server, a windows just appears where i can enter a smb:// path, no "Windows share", any idea? I have the newest ubuntu, 13.04 i think :)

Comment: Ok, things are changing. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: But if you enter smb://yourserver.yourdomain.com in the window you should be able to get the User/Domain/Password window. See also [link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/how-to-access-windows-network-shares-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/)

Comment: This is an old thread to this question: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259207/how-do-i-access-a-password-protected-share-from-nautilus)